Prometheus Java client library 1.x replacement for simpleclient-logback
I am trying to upgrade prometheus simpleclient 0.16.0 in my java app to prometheus client library 1.x.
I am looking at Migration guide but I see no obvious replacement for InstrumentedAppender from simpleclient-logback which counts log statements at different levels.
What is the replacement of this class in prometheus java client library?
